# Conditionally display Woocommerce checkout field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

On a Wordpress website,I am currently trying to setup a Woocommerce and [Learnpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/learnpress/) plugins. I Use [Woocommerce Checkout Add-ons](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-checkout-add-ons/) commercial plugin which allows to create some additional checkout fields.

I would like to display conditionally some checkout fields only when certain Learnpress courses are present in the checkout cart.

The code present in the checkout plugin is as follows:

```
<?php if ( $add_on_fields ) : ?>

<div id="wc_checkout_add_ons">
<?php
    foreach ( $add_on_fields as $key => $field ) :
        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, WC()->checkout()->get_value( 
        $key ) );
    endforeach;
?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

So started going this route:

```
<div id="wc_checkout_add_ons">
<?php 
    $course_category = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'course_category' );
    echo $course_category; 
    if ($course_category == 'weekend-intensives') { 
        foreach ( $add_on_fields as $key => $field ) : 
            woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, WC()->checkout()->get_value( $key ) ); 
        endforeach; 
    } else { 
        echo ('Proceed with checkout'); 
    } 
?> 
</div>
```

Right now I don't even get that initial echo for `$course_category` so I know that I am already wrong there...

I need to figure out what the code would be for getting the **learnpress course category** of the course in the checkout/cart. 
I know there is a lot more to it than this and I am likely way off, but I am willing to work through it with some assistance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change your question to be the specific issue - something like: Wordpress - conditionally display woocommerce checkout field.

Comment: @Alan This is related to WooCommerce plugin… There is no checkout fields without it. As the question is tagged Wordpress, no need to add it in the title.

Comment: I havem't worked with learnpress, but you can use `WC()->cart->get_cart()` to get list of products that are present in your cart, then you can write a condition that only show the checkout field if a certain product ( the learnpress related product ) is in the cart.

Comment: @Innervation As you modifying plugin core files actually, or are this templates that you can override? Because overriding core files is not really the way, as you will have to insert your changes after each update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`has_term()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) specific WordPress conditional function for custom taxonomies and custom taxonomies as "Product categories" **or for your case** "Course categories" that you can use easily.

1) You need to check cart items, to see if there is a cart item that remains to 'weekend-intensives' Course category and this has to be done at the beginning of the code. This way you can alter the existing condition `if ( $add_on_fields ) :`…

2) You need to be sure that the **Course categories** taxonomy are applicable to WooCommerce **product custom post type**. If not you will not be able to check for any **Course categories** cart items.

So the correct way to do it is:

```
<?php
    ## ---- Custom code start here ---- ##
    $is_in_cart = false;

    // Checking cart items for specific "Course category"
    foreach( WC->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        // Here your Course category
        if( has_term( 'weekend-intensives', 'course_category', $cart_item['product_id'] ){
            $is_in_cart = true; // Found
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    // adding our condition in existing code if statement
    if ( $add_on_fields && $is_in_cart ) : 

    ## ---- Custom code Ends here ---- ##

    // if ( $add_on_fields ) :
?>

<div id="wc_checkout_add_ons">
<?php
    foreach ( $add_on_fields as $key => $field ) :
        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, WC()->checkout()->get_value( $key ) );
    endforeach;
?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This is untested, but it should work (if Course categories are applicable to WC products)

---

**UPDATE**

Check if a product ID works with "weekend-intensives" course category:

- Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).
- Set inside it the correct product ID to check and save.
- Go in archives pages or product pages to see the result (once saved).

The code:

```
// Checking for "weekend-intensives" course category in shop and product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', function(){
    // Only for admin user role
    if( ! current_user_can('edit_products')) return;

    // ==> BELOW set your product ID to check
    $product_id = 43;

    // Output the raw cart object data
    if( has_term( 'weekend-intensives', 'course_category', $product_id ){
        echo '<pre>YES! This product works with "weekend-intensives" course category</pre>';
    } else {
        echo '<pre>This product DOES NOT WORK with "weekend-intensives" course category</pre>';
    }
}, 987 );
```

Comment: Thanks Aztec.  Fixed a couple syntax errors and got the page to load, however it now does not display the add-on field.

Comment: @Innervation So certainly maybe 'course_category' is not working with product post type…

Comment: how can I check this?

Comment: @Innervation **I have updated my answer (at the end)** … There is a [commercial add on for wooCommerce](https://thimpress.com/product/woocommerce-add-on-for-learnpress/) do you use it already? …

Comment: Ok, update.  I checked out the checkout process again both with Weekend-Intensive courses and non-weekend-intensives courses and the add-on field DOES populate for the non-weekend intensives....We HAVE to be close here.

Comment: Got it to work!  It was just changing the logic to be true if is_in_cart and has_terms